# User input as double/int, output as superscript for exponential/root functions

Tags: java, formatting

So I am making a calculator, and one of the parts of it is roots. I have looked and have not found any solutions that can take a user input and output it as a superscript. I have tried text attribute and many other formatting commands but none of them have worked. Any tips?

This is what it looks like now: 3√8

> This is what I want: ³√8

Here is my code, I added comments to make it easier to understand and removed all irreverent pieces. I can elaborate if you still have questions. Thanks for the help!

```
package calculator;
    // import
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import java.awt.font.TextAttribute;

public static void rootsCalculator() {
    // define variables
        int confirm = 2;
        double base;
        double root;
        double answer;

    // loop for "no" to confirm
    do {
            // output to ask for base and power
            System.out.print("\nEnter the base number: ");
            Scanner inputRootBase = new Scanner(System.in);
            base = inputRootBase.nextDouble();

            System.out.print("Enter the exponent: ");
            Scanner inputRootRoot = new Scanner(System.in);
            root = inputRootRoot.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("Is this what you want to solve?"
                + "/n" + TextAttribute.SUPERSCRIPT(root) + "\u221A" + style1.format(base));

            confirm = confirm();
        } while (confirm == 2);
}
```

Comment: I doubt the console supports that kind of output - and `TextAttribute` (or any *awt* classes) cannot be combined with console output

Comment: @Rohan Gupta : I think you'll have to open your own window using swing or awt to display such a thing.